If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^ka_{p^k}$ converges aswell

If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}p^ka_{p^k}$ converges aswell

Edit: $a_n$ is decreasing and converges to $0$.
This is my attempt:
I tried to use the root test.
We have $p\in \mathbb{N},2\leq p$
If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then $\lim_\limits{n\rightarrow \infty}{a_n}=0$ holds.
Then $\limsup_\limits{k\rightarrow \infty}{\sqrt[k]{{p^ka_{p^k}}}}$$=$$\limsup_\limits{k\rightarrow \infty}{p\cdot \sqrt[k]{{a_{p^k}}}}$$=0$ since $a_n$ converges to $0$. By the root test we are done.
Does the application of the root test really work?

This seems like a good use case for the Cauchy condensation test at first glance to me.

@CameronWilliams Thank you! I will look at this test.

@peterag I thought this would work since $p$ is fixed. Sorry

This is certainly not true for the original version of this, where the $a_n$s were not required to be decreasing. Take for example $a_n = \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges, but for any $p$:

If $p$ is even then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p^na_{p^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{p^n}\frac{p^n}{p^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1$ which certainly diverges.

If $p$ is odd then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p^na_{p^n} = (-1)\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{p^n}{p^n} = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1$ which also certainly diverges.



ETA: If on the other hand the $a_n$s are decreasing [and nonnegative] then yes, $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}p^ka_{p^k}$ does converge if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges:
As $p$ must be in $\mathbb{N}$, assume $p$ must be at least $2$, this is obvious if $p$ os $1$. Then:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n \ = \ a_1 +\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \Big(\sum_{n=p^{k}+1}^{p^{k+1}} a_n\Big)$$
$$ \ge \Big(\frac{p-1}{p}\Big) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p^{k+1}a_{p^{k+1}} \ \ge \ \Big(\frac{1}{2}\Big) \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p^{k+1}a_{p^{k+1}} ,$$
where for the last relation we used $a_n \ge a_{p^{k+1}} $ for each $n \le p^k$ and thus $\Big(\sum_{n=p^{k-1}+1}^{p^k} a_n\Big)$ $\ge$ $(p^{k+1}-p^{k})a_{p^{k+1}}$ $=$ $\big(\frac{p-1}{p}\Big) \cdot p^{k+1}a_{p^{k+1}}$. So in particular, if $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is finite, then so must be $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} p^{k+1}a_{p^{k+1}}$ $=$ $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} p^ka_{p^k}$.

ETA: This strikes me as a natural follow-up question so I'll address it here: Note that say, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2a_{n^2}$ may not converge even if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ does, and with the $a_n$s decreasing. Take $a_n= \frac{1}{n \log^2 (n+2)}$. Then $\sum_{n=1} a_n$ converges but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^2a_{n^2}$ $=$ $\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} t^2 \cdot \frac{1}{t^2 \log^2(t^2+2)} = \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\log^2(t^2+1)}$ diverges.

Sorry I forgot to mention that $a_n$ is decreasing and converges to 0.

Thank you very much. Sorry for the mess.

There are some indexing issues in your sums since the double series has no term $a_1$ and your summing over $k$ starting at $k = 1$ should start at $k = 0$, while at $k = 0$ your index $n = p^{k-1} + 1$ doesn't make sense.

@KCd Thanks, I believe I fixed these.

The Cauchy condensation test is the case $p = 2$, where it is a necessary and sufficient condition for convergence of the original series when $a_n$ decreases monotonically to $0$.  The test the OP asks about, with general $p \geq 2$, is also necessary and sufficient under the same condition on the $a_n$'s since we can derive the inequalities
$$
\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n \leq (p-1)\sum_{k \geq 0} p^ka_{p^k} \leq p\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n.
$$
(If you look at the Wikipedia page for the Cauchy condensation test you'll see at the start of the section "Estimate" the inequalities $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n) \leq \sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^nf(2^n) \leq 2\sum_{n=1}^\infty f(n)$, which I had in mind when working out the inequalities above with $2$ replaced by $p$.) The first inequality is due to
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n & = (a_1 + \cdots + a_{p-1}) + (a_p + \cdots + a_{p^2-1}) + (a_{p^2} + \cdots + a_{p^3-1}) + \cdots \\
& \leq (p-1)a_1 + (p^2-p)a_p + (p^3-p^2)a_{p^2} + \cdots \\
& = (p-1)a_1 + (p-1)pa_p + (p-1)p^2a_{p^2} + \cdots \\
& = (p-1)\sum_{k \geq 0} p^ka_{p^k},
\end{align*}
where the inequality in the second step is based on $a_n$ monotonically decreasing and the number of terms from $a_{p^k}$ to $a_{p^{k+1}-1}$ being $p^{k+1}-1 - (p^k - 1) = p^{k+1}-p^k = (p-1)p^k$.
The second inequality is derived as follows:
\begin{align*}
(p-1)\sum_{k \geq 0} p^ka_{p^k} & = (p-1)a_1 + (p-1)pa_p + (p-1)p^2a_{p^2} + (p-1)p^3a_{p^3} + \cdots \\
& = (p-1)a_1 + p((p-1)a_p + (p-1)pa_{p^2} + (p-1)p^2a_{p^3} + \cdots) \\
& = (p-1)a_1 + p((p-1)a_p + (p^2-p)a_{p^2} + (p^3-p^2)a_{p^3} + \cdots) \\
& \leq (p-1)a_1 + p((a_2 + \cdots + a_p) + (a_{p+1} + \cdots + a_{p^2}) + (a_{p^2+1} + \cdots + a_{p^3}) + \cdots) \\
& \leq pa_1 + p(a_2 + \cdots + a_p + a_{p+1} + \cdots + a_{p^2} + a_{p^2+1} + \cdots + a_{p^3} + \cdots) \\ 
& = p\sum_{n \geq 1} a_n.
\end{align*}

The conclusion is well known as the condensation test. Namely if $a_n\searrow 0$ and $n_k$ is a sequence of increasing natural numbers then $$ \sum a_n<\infty \implies \sum (n_k-n_{k-1})a_{n_k}<\infty $$ The proof is easy, based on  $$(n_k-n_{k-1})a_{n_k}\le \sum_{n=n_{k-1}+1}^{n_k} a_n $$ In the OP case $n_k=p^k$. Then $n_k-n_{k-1}=(1-p^{-1})p^k.$
The conclusion does not hold for $n_k=p^k$ if $a_n$ is not decreasing. It does not hold even for positive sequence $a_n$. Indeed consider $\sum n^{-2}.$ Change the order of summation so that $a_{p^k}=k^{-2}.$ Then $\sum a_n=\sum n^{-2}<\infty.$ However $$\sum  p^ka_{p^k}=\sum p^kk^{-2}=\infty $$
